# What is print(f"...")

Tags: python, f-string

I am reading through a python script that takes an input of XML files and outputs an XML file. However, I do not understand the printing syntax. Can someone please explain what `f` in `print(f"...")` does?

```
args = parser.parser_args()

print(f"Input directory: {args.input_directory}")
print(f"Output directory: {args.output_directory}")
```

Comment: [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-denote-f-strings).This syntax is available only from python 3.6 onwards

Comment: They are f-string. It's a newly introduced concept from Python 3.6
https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The `f` means [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals)  and it's new in `Python 3.6`.

---

> A *formatted string literal* or *f-string* is a string literal that is
> prefixed with `f` or `F`. These strings may contain replacement
> fields, which are expressions delimited by curly braces `{}`. While
> other string literals always have a constant value, formatted strings
> are really expressions evaluated at run time.

---

Some examples of formatted string literals:

```
>>> name = "Fred"
>>> f"He said his name is {name}."
"He said his name is Fred."

>>> name = "Fred"
>>> f"He said his name is {name!r}."
"He said his name is Fred."

>>> f"He said his name is {repr(name)}." # repr() is equivalent to !r
"He said his name is Fred."

>>> width = 10
>>> precision = 4
>>> value = decimal.Decimal("12.34567")
>>> f"result: {value:{width}.{precision}}" # nested fields
result: 12.35

>>> today = datetime(year=2023, month=1, day=27)
>>> f"{today:%B %d, %Y}" # using date format specifier
January 27, 2023

>>> number = 1024
>>> f"{number:#0x}" # using integer format specifier
0x400
```

Comment: For those who are new to python: `The repr() function returns a printable representational string of the given object.`

Comment: @PrashantZombade what would be the difference between `str(name)` and `repr(name)` in this case?

Comment: @RicardoBarrosLourenço https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr

Answer (score 52):

In Python 3.6, the f-string, *formatted string literal*, was introduced([PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/)). In short, it is a way to format your string that is more readable and fast.

Example:

```py
agent_name = 'James Bond'
kill_count = 9


# old ways
print("%s has killed %d enemies" % (agent_name,kill_count))

print('{} has killed {} enemies'.format(agent_name,kill_count))
print('{name} has killed {kill} enemies'.format(name=agent_name,kill=kill_count))
    

# f-strings way
print(f'{agent_name} has killed {kill_count} enemies')
```

The `f` or `F`  in front of strings tell Python to look at the values , expressions or instance inside {} and substitute them with the variables values or results if exists. The best thing about f-formatting is that you can do cool stuff in {}, e.g. `{kill_count * 100}`.

You can use it to debug using print e.g.

```py
print(f'the {agent_name=}.')
# the agent_name='James Bond'
```

Formatting, such as zero-padding, float and percentage rounding is made easier:

```py
print(f'{agent_name} shoot with {9/11 : .2f} or {9/11: .1%} accuracy')
# James Bond shoot with  0.82 or  81.8% accuracy
```

Even cooler is the ability to nest and format. Example date

```py
from datetime import datetime

lookup = {
    '01': 'st',
    '21': 'st',
    '31': 'st',
    '02': 'nd',
    '22': 'nd',
    '03': 'rd',
    '23': 'rd'
}

print(f"{datetime.now(): %B %d{lookup.get('%B', 'th')} %Y}")

# April 14th 2022
```

Pretty formatting is also easier

```py
tax = 1234

print(f'{tax:,}') # separate 1k \w comma
# 1,234

print(f'{tax:,.2f}') # all two decimals 
# 1,234.00

print(f'{tax:~>8}') # pad left with ~ to fill eight characters or < other direction
# ~~~~1234

print(f'{tax:~^20}') # centre and pad
# ~~~~~~~~1234~~~~~~~~
```

The `__format__` allows you to funk with this feature. Example

```py
class Money:
    
    def __init__(self, currency='€'):
        self.currency = currency
        
    def __format__(self, value):
        
        return f"{self.currency} {float(value):.2f}"
        
        
tax = 12.34
money = Money(currency='$')
print(f'{money: {tax}}')
# $ 12.34
```

There is much more. Readings:

- [PEP 498 Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
- [Python String Formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/)

Comment: "more readable"... Seriously, what was wrong with "...".format()? It looks less and less "pythonic" with this "print(f'....' {})". I like progress in code but this only adds things to add things.

Comment: I hope my answer does not entail there is something wrong with "{}...”.format. Just like " ".join(...), I think something like format("...{}", ...) and similar join(..., " ") would be "more readable".  There is nothing wrong. Just readability which is also subjective. ☺️

Answer (score 19):

the f string is also known as the literal string to insert a variable into the string and make it part so instead of doing

```
x = 12
y = 10

word_string = x + ' plus ' + y + 'equals: ' + (x+y)
```

instead, you can do

```
x = 12
y = 10

word_string = f'{x} plus {y} equals: {x+y}'
output: 12 plus 10 equals: 22
```

this will also help with spacing due to it will do exactly as the string is written

Comment: There's a missing the closing quote on the 2nd `word_string`

Answer (score 4):

A string prefixed with `'f'` or `'F'` and writing expressions as `{expression}` is a way to format string, which can include the value of Python expressions inside it.

Take these code as an example:

```
def area(length, width):
    return length * width

l = 4
w = 5

print("length =", l, "width =", w, "area =", area(l, w))  # normal way
print(f"length = {l} width = {w} area = {area(l,w)}")     # Same output as above
print("length = {l} width = {w} area = {area(l,w)}")      # without f prefixed
```

Output:

```
length = 4 width = 5 area = 20
length = 4 width = 5 area = 20
length = {l} width = {w} area = {area(l,w)}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
args = parser.parser_args()

print(f"Input directory: {args.input_directory}")
print(f"Output directory: {args.output_directory}")
```

is the same as

```
print("Input directory: {}".format(args.input_directory))
print("Output directory: {}".format(args.output_directory))
```

it is also the same as

```
print("Input directory: "+args.input_directory)
print("Output directory: "+args.output_directory)
```

Comment: Note that strictly speaking, these three techniques are not equivalent. They each have different performance characteristics and vary in how they handle non-string arguments.

Answer (score 2):

f-string in python lets you format data for printing using string templates. 
*Below example will help you to clarify*

**With f-string**

```
name = 'Niroshan'
age  = 25;
print(f"Hello I'm {name} and {age} years young")
```

> Hello I'm Niroshan and 25 years young

---

**Without f-string**

```
name = 'Niroshan'
age  = 25;
print("Hello I'm {name} and {age} years young")
```

> Hello I'm {name} and {age} years young

Answer (score 0):

f function is Transferring data to other places in your content.
It mostly used Changeable Data.

class  Methods ():
def  **init**(self ,F,L,E,S,T):
self.FirstName=F
self.LastName=L
self.Email=E
self.Salary=S
self.Time =T

```
    def  Salary_Msg(self):
        #f is called function f
        #next use {write in}
        return f{self.firstname} {self.Lastname} earns AUD {self.Salary}per {self.Time} "
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).