# How do I check each letter in a word is either a vowel or consonant?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, cpu-word

```
def check_v_c(word):
    for i in word:
        if i in "AEIOUaeiou":
            return i

        else:
            i in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"


print(check_v_c("Money"))
```

I was trying to loop each letter using the for loop.

Comment: Then don't return inside the loop. Also it should be `elif`

Comment: instead of `return` ->`print` also you can remove `i in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"` in else part and can directly print that.. it is not a vowel..!

Comment: In the `if` statement, you have `return`, which exits the function immediately.  Don't do that.

Comment: Also, in the `else` statement, you're checking if `i` is a consonant, but then you're not doing anything with the _result_ of the check.

Comment: What is the function supposed to return?

Comment: There are more conditions than vowel and consonant - digits, punctuation, spaces and etc... What should be done with those?

Comment: When writing a question, include the desired result and what went wrong. Do you want a list of true/false values?

Answer (score 2):

I hope, this will work for your solution use string class to check for punctuation

```
import string
def check_v_c(word):
    result = []
    for i in word:
        if i.lower() in "aeiou":
            result.append(f'{i} is a vowel')
        elif i in string.punctuation:
            result.append(f'{i} is a punctuation')
        else:
            result.append(f'{i} is a consonant')
    return result
print('\n'.join(check_v_c("Mon.ey")))
```

Comment: You could use `for i in word.lower(): if i in "aeiou"` so you don't have to apply the `lower()` method in each loop.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to remove `else` as if `if` is `False` the it will run for loop again

```
def check_v_c(word):
  for i in word:
    if i in "AEIOUaeiou":
        return i


print(check_v_c("Money"))
```

But if you want to pass something then you can

```
def check_v_c(word):
  for i in word:
    if i in "AEIOUaeiou":
        return i

    else:
        "It is not vowel"


print(check_v_c("Money"))
```

Comment: def check_v_c(word):
    for i in word:
        if i in "AEIOUaeiou":
            print(i, " is vowel")
        else:
            print(i, "is consonant")

print(check_v_c("Money"))               It returns None at the end. Can youtell me why? Thanks

Comment: @HamzaKhatib Yeh because you r trying to print the `function` (i.e., `check_v_c()`) now as it doesn't return any thing so it is returning `None`

Comment: @HamzaKhatib **Try this code :** `def check_v_c(word): 
    for i in word: 
        if i in "AEIOUaeiou": 
            print(f"{i} is vowel")
        else: 
            print(f"{i} is consonant")
                    
check_v_c("Money")`

Answer (score 0):

- you need to change `return i` to `print(f"{i} is vowel")` which will print something like that (o is vowel)
- and if the first condition is `False` the letter will be consonant so you need to change `i in "BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"` to `print(f"{i} is consonant")` which will print something like that (m is consonant)
- if you don't understand the format i use to print, i suggest you to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150426/what-is-printf)
- To optimize the code: use `word.lower()` which will reduce the number of comparisons.

```
def check_v_c(word):
    # Make a for loop and convert the input to lowercase to reduce the number of comparisons
    for i in word.lower():
        if i in "aeiou":
            print(f"{i} is vowel")
        else:
            print(f"{i} is consonant")

print(check_v_c("Money"))
```

you can see output
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnFQm.jpg)